# Two datagrids with same sorting wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, datagrid

I have two datagrids which is bound to two datatables as itemsource
[Datagrids](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6SCY.png). I want to be able to sort both datagrid columns when clicked on one of the headers. When the property: "CanUserSortColumns="True"" is set to true, the datagrids will not sort together. What I want is when clicked on column header, the row from either datagrid 1 or datagrid 2 will follow the sorting, so the row matches the sorting.

I have looked into this abit and saw that dataviewer can be used to sorting(since it is bound to datatable), also saw that a  CollectionView can be used, but I cant see any examples of doing this with two datagrids, only with one.

Sorting only one datagrid(What I have):
[Image of what I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/riSwX.gif)

Sorting both datagrid by clicking header(What I need):
[Image of what i need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSXS0.gif)

Is there a why to do this? Both datagrids have the same number of rows.

Comment: You need a common field in the two tables so you can use a JOIN.  Then to get one table use JOIN.  Otherwise you have to assign a row number to each table and then join by the row number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an attached property that should help you, I just coded it kinda quick and dirty so I think you can make sure I didn't forget anything before using (and edit the answer if I did). You can use it this way in XAML :

```
<DataGrid local:DatagridBehaviour.SyncSortingWith="{Binding ElementName=otherDataGrid}"/>
<DataGrid Name="otherDataGrid"/>
```

**Attached Property :**

```
public static class DatagridBehaviour
{
    public static DataGrid GetSyncSortingWith(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (DataGrid)obj.GetValue(SyncSortingWithProperty);
    }

    public static void SetSyncSortingWith(DependencyObject obj, DataGrid value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(SyncSortingWithProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SyncSortingWithProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SyncSortingWith", typeof(DataGrid), typeof(DatagridBehaviour), new PropertyMetadata(OnSyncSortingWithChanged));

    private static void OnSyncSortingWithChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (d is DataGrid source)
        {
            source.Sorting -= DataGridSorting;
            if (e.NewValue is DataGrid other)
            {
                other.Sorting += DataGridSorting;
                source.Sorting += DataGridSorting;
            }

            if (e.OldValue is DataGrid previous)
            {
                previous.Sorting -= DataGridSorting;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void DataGridSorting(object sender, DataGridSortingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is DataGrid dataGrid)
        {
            DataGridColumn column = dataGrid.Columns[0];
            dataGrid.Items.SortDescriptions.Clear();
            dataGrid.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription(column.SortMemberPath, column.SortDirection == ListSortDirection.Ascending ? ListSortDirection.Descending : ListSortDirection.Ascending));

            // May not be needed
            dataGrid.Items.Refresh();
        }
    }
}
```

The only thing you'll need for it to work is having the same bindings path on the columns of both datagrids.